# How to change path using re.sub in string keeping the same file name with extension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to change some paths using `re.sub`, here is what I have tried:

```
import re
a = """
-v /path/fixed/verilog/a.v
-v /path/fixed/models/syn/vds/b.bv
-v /path/fixed/lnd/vss/neg.v
"""

b = re.sub(r'(\/path\/fixed.*)\/[^.]*', '$root/new/path', a)
print(b)
```

I see following output:

```
-v $root/new/path.v
-v $root/new/path.bv
-v $root/new/path.v
```

Expected output:

```
-v $root/new/path/a.v
-v $root/new/path/b.bv
-v $root/new/path/neg.v
```

I need to replace whole path before last `/` and keep file name with extension intact.
I am missing something here, can someone help me figure that out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a capture group:

```
b = re.sub(r'/path/fixed/.*/([^/\s]+)', '$root/new/path/\\1', a)
print(b)
```

This prints:

```
-v $root/new/path/a.v
-v $root/new/path/b.bv
-v $root/new/path/neg.v
```

The regex pattern `/path/fixed/.*/([^/\s]+)` will match an entire path, capturing the final path component in `\1`.  Note that `([^/\s]+)` will not match across newlines.

Comment: It changed only last line for me. First 2 lines remained same.

Comment: It is working, [Check the demo](https://rextester.com/CDHIF87043).

Comment: I had tried first version which was before your edit, now it works. Thanks!